# Adjust one subplot's height in absolute way (not relative) in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have **two subplots** in Matplotlib (embedded in a GUI):

- Subplot 1: Height is fixed at a certain amount of pixels.
- Subplot 2: Height takes up the remainder of the whole figure's height (allowing for margins).

In both cases these are the same width.

GridSpec seems to not allow absolute sizing, only relative sizing.  I **don't** want Subplot 1 to stretch its height with the window resizing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then this code might help. It uses axes instead of subplots, which give more absolute control over the position of the plots within the figure.

```
    import pylab as pl
    # use pylab.Axes(figure, [left, bottom, width, height]) 
    # where each value in the frame is between 0 and 1

    #top
    figure = pl.figure()
    axes = pl.Axes(figure, [.4,.4,.25,.25])
    figure.add_axes(axes) 
    pl.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

    #bottom
    axes = pl.Axes(figure, [.4,.1,.25,.25])
    figure.add_axes(axes) 
    pl.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

    pl.show()
```

If this is not what you meant, please post a snippet of code or an example to clarify.